# How to remove thermocouple from this manifold door?

Tags: water-heater, hot-water

It has a black object that seems to be secured down by a U shaped clasp. I cannot see how the clasp can be removed. Everything is tight and doesn't appear that a tool can fit anywhere to loosen it up.

Front
[image: front]
Back
[image: back]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it off by using a hammer and a screwdriver. I hammered a flathead screwdriver onto the end of the clasp-list piece. The clasp is intended to be inserted underneath the black holders and thus can be removed by pulling/pushing it out the opposite direction.

Here is an image of where the screwdriver should be placed to hit off the U-shaped clasp. This is looking at the same place on the second image of the original question but turned upside down.

[image]